# Printing a part of an integer in a list

Tags: python, micropython

To print an entire integer under a dictionary key, the following code works:

```
print(config[('r' + str(config['lines']))])
```

However, if I want to print only the first number and add `[1]` as so:

```
print(config[('r' + str(config['lines']))][1])
```

I get the error **TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**. How do I print the first number of the integer only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the number to a string so you can subscript it.

```
print(str(config[('r' + str(config['lines']))])[0])
```

Indexes start at `0`, so you need to use `[0]` to get the first digit.

Comment: What you are saying is that one can't subscript integers, correct?

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now!